# Getting permission denied error on Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

So I have 2 schemas in 1 database, we'll call it `schema1` and `schema2`.

I have a **view** on `schema1` that tries to do `select from a view on schema2`.

I have `schema1` select group users who have select access on `schema1` and they shouldn't be able to do select on `schema2`.

I tried using `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO schema1_select_group`.

However, when trying to do `select on view1` I am getting an error:

> SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation view2

I figured `GRANT USAGE` should be enough since we didn't want the `schema1` user to be able to `select from view2 on schema2` directly.